# Stop Spring standalone application

Tags: spring

I have created Spring Standalone application and I have deployed that on Unix box. I have created jar file that I am executing using java -jar JarName.jar command.
Is there any way to stop this standalone process apart from using JMX?

Thanks
Sach

Comment: You can kill the java process.

Comment: I dont want to kill unix java process using Kill command as it is not advisable on prod environment.

Comment: Your question is essentially "how do I send a SIGINT to a process" - and the `kill` command is *the* way to do this in Unix, regardless of how "dangerous" its name sounds to you. This however implies that you can actually log in to the prod environment which is the real scary thing here.